# several setSQL-calls in one function

Tags: carto, carto.js

I have a carto-map that consists of four layers.
The users of my map should have the option to choose the map projection. 
For one layer this works fine:

```
$('#selectProjection').on('click', function() {
            var srid = $(this).val();
            firstLayer.setSQL("SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, " + srid + ") as the_geom_webmercator FROM firsttable"); 
 });
```

But i have to project all four layers. If a add the same query just for another layer, there is no layer projected at all. 
This code doesn't work:

```
$('#selectProjection').on('click', function() {
            var srid = $(this).val();
            firstLayer.setSQL("SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, " + srid + ") as the_geom_webmercator FROM firsttable"); 
            secondLayer.setSQL("SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, " + srid + ") as the_geom_webmercator FROM secondtable");
});
```

Does anoyone have an idea?

EDIT: a js fiddle with the whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/nmrs11kq/11/

Comment: Why is it failing? Could you share the whole code? You can use a js fiddle or plkr link.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added a link in the original post.

Comment: sorry, i had to update the link. i realized the code wasn't complete

Comment: You forget to add CARTO.js library, but I was able to replicate your issue. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your browser console and go to the `Network` tab, and look for the call that is triggered by your dropdown menu, there is a PostGIS error that tells you CARTO cannot transform some points located on certain latitudes:

```
Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (-37.543 -106.778 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)\nin executeQuery Full sql was: 'SELECT ST_AsTWKB(ST_Simplify(ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints(\"the_geom_webmercator\",1e-05),1e-05,true),5) AS geom FROM (SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, 953009) as the_geom_webmercator FROM magmachron) as cdbq WHERE \"the_geom_webmercator\" && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(-20037508.3 20037508.25881302,-20037508.25881302 20037508.3)'::box3d, 3857)'\n"],"errors_with_context":[{"type":"layer","message":"Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  transform: couldn't project point (-37.543 -106.778 0): latitude or longitude exceeded limits (-14)\nin executeQuery Full sql was: 'SELECT ST_AsTWKB(ST_Simplify(ST_RemoveRepeatedPoints(\"the_geom_webmercator\",1e-05),1e-05,true),5) AS geom FROM (SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, 953009) as the_geom_webmercator FROM magmachron) as cdbq WHERE \"the_geom_webmercator\" && ST_SetSRID('BOX3D(-20037508.3 20037508.25881302,-20037508.25881302 20037508.3)'::box3d, 3857)'\n
```

So it looks like the there are certain points within the `magmachron` dataset that you need to filter. You can check that when commenting these lines, the code works:

```
// magmachron.setSQL("SELECT cartodb_id, st_transform(the_geom, " + srid + ") as the_geom_webmercator" + " FROM magmachron");
```

Finally, you can find similar (working) application to the one your are building [here](https://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/6d19c773bb2764837c285c89da984c1d).

Comment: Thank you very much! I absolutely ignored that it could be a data issue.